# Access denied or permission denied triggered if document loaded to iframe is stored on Azure Blob Storage

Tags: iframe, azure-storage, cloud-hosting, azure-blob-storage

I have a website hosted on Windows Azure Cloud. In one of the aspx pages, I have an iframe. Into this iframe I will be loading a html page that is stored in Windows Azure Blob storage. When I do this, I get an instant error on the webpage when i try to access the contents/properties of the iframe. The error is

"Access Denied" or "Permission Denied". Can anyone please strike me with a solution to the same. I guess it is one problem that is not addressed by the people in Windows Azure.

Thanks in advance

Regards

Sandeep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this problem sorted out. 
Thanks to Wenchao who is an MSDN Moderator.
Here is the link where you can find out how I solved this.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredata/thread/df51d3ef-d92c-41ae-8331-6a18433aa78c

Answer (score 0):

> when i try to access the contents/properties of the iframe

What exactly do you mean by this? Are you trying to access those contents from script running in the parent frame? That's disallowed by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Script from one domain isn't allowed to access contents of a frame from another domain, and the page from blob storage will be from something.blob.core.windows.net. If you really need to pass data from one frame to the other, you can push it into the URL fragment of the other frame:

```
parent.location.hash = encodeURIComponent("some data we need to transfer");
```

Generally though, it's best to put any scripts that use the contents of the iframe in the frame itself.

Comment: I am trying to do 

FrameDoc = (pFrame.Document ? pFrame.Document : pFrame.contentDocument); 

where pFrame is the ifram
and pFrame.contentDocument and pFrame.Document is giving me Acess Denied or Permission Denied error. So how do I go about changing this code to solve this ?

Sandeep

Comment: That depends on what you intend to do with the document element once you get it. If your script doesn't need to access any data from the parent frame, it's easiest to put the script inside the HTML page that you're serving from blob storage. Then you can have `<script>document.doWhateverYouWant()</script>` and it will execute inside the context of the iframe's contentWindow. That means that the `document` variable in your new script refers to the same `pFrame.contentDocument` that you couldn't access from the outer frame.

Comment: I need to execute few scripts inside the iframe too